# Convert a hex number in a varchar column to unsigned nteger?

Tags: mysql, long-integer

I have a table with a column `hexval` containing varchar(16) values like

```
abcdef0123456789
deadbeefcafe0000
fffffffffffffff0
0000000000000000
```

Is there a way, **using MySQL**, to say

```
SELECT convert(hexval)  to 64-bit unsigned integer
  FROM table
```

which will return a numeric result rather than a text string?

If not for 64-bit numbers, how about for 32-bit unsigned numbers? or decimal numbers?

Comment: Isn't that what the `CONV(N,from_base,to_base)` does? Try `SELECT CONV('deadbeefcafe0000',16,10);` According to the docs it works with 64-bit precision and by uses unsigned unless to_base is negative. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding something here

Comment: @jpw thanks, missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below results it may help you.

```
select conv('abcdef0123456789',16,10) from dual;
+--------------------------------+
| conv('abcdef0123456789',16,10) |`Use the conv function`
+--------------------------------+
| 12379813738877118345           |
+--------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

`CONV()` is the function.

```
SELECT CONV(hexval,16,10)) number
  FROM table
```

does the trick.